# Как сравнить элементы структуры

Tags: c++, структуры

Не работает проверка:

```
(authorization.UserName == ptr->UserName && authorization.Password == ptr->Password)
```

хоть и все данные верны (проверял через дебагер)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <conio.h>

struct Person {
    char UserName[30]{};
    char Password[30]{};
};

char* InputUserName() {
    char* username = new char[30] {};
    cout << "UserName: ";
    cin >> username;
    return username;
}

char* InputPassword() {
    char* password = new char[30] {};
    cout << "Password: ";
    cin >> password;
    return password;
}



Person CreatePerson(const char* password, const char* username) {
    if (username == nullptr || password == nullptr) {
        throw "Name or surname can not be empty!";
    }
    Person person = Person();

    strcpy_s(person.UserName, username);
    strcpy_s(person.Password, password);
    return person;
}

Person registration;
Person authorization;
Person* ptr;


void Registration();

void Authorization() {
    int choice = -1;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "\t\t\t\t_______________________Authorization__________________________" << endl;
    
        Person authorization = CreatePerson(InputPassword(), InputUserName());

        if (authorization.UserName == ptr->UserName && authorization.Password == ptr->Password) {
            system("cls");
            cout << "\t\t\t\t___________________Authorization Successfully___________________" << endl;
            cout << "\t\t\t\tEnter '0' to continue: ";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 0) {
                while (EndFunc) {
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "\t\t\t\t_____________________Restaurant__________________________" << "\n\n";
                    PrintMenu(MainMenu, menuLength);
                    SelectedOption();

                    _getch();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            system("cls");
            cout << "\t\t\t\t______________Incorrect password or username!__________________" << endl;
            cout << "\t\t\t\t1. Repeat\n\t\t\t\t2. Registration\n\t\t\t\t3. Exit " << endl;
            cout << "\t\t\t\tEnter: ";

            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1) {
                system("cls");
                Authorization();
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                system("cls");
                Registration();
            }
            else if (choice == 3) {
                system("cls");
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 0x09);
                cout << "\t\t\t\tThank you for using this program!\n\n\n";
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 0x0c);
                EndFunc = false;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (choice == 3);
}


void Registration() {
    bool match = 0;

    system("cls");
    cout << "\t\t\t\t_________________________Registration_________________________" << endl;

    Person registration = CreatePerson(InputPassword(), InputUserName());

    ptr = &registration;

    match = 1;
    system("cls");

    cout << "\t\t\t\t______________________Registered Successfully______________________" << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t\tEntar '0' for Authorization: ";
    bool choice = 0;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 0)
        system("cls");
    Authorization();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сравниваете С-строки, т.е. по сути, указатели `char*`. Такое сравнение просто сравнивает значения двух *указателей*, т.е. лежат ли строки в одном месте в памяти (конечно, нет!).

Сравнивать же надо [*содержимое строк*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), т.е. вместо

```
authorization.UserName == ptr->UserName
```

сравнение должно выглядеть как

```
strcmp(authorization.UserName, ptr->UserName) == 0
```